# Eclipse listing but not running unit tests, how to fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When running a specific junit test in the Apache Jackrabbit project, Eclipse goes through the motions of running the test, but the test is never run, debugger breakpoints are never fired, and the results are that zero out of eight tests were run, and no errors were reported.

https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/trunk/jackrabbit-spi2dav/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/spi2dav/ConnectionTest.java

The confusion is that the tests, after the run, don't indicate whether they succeeded, failed, or were explicitly skipped, and I cannot see anything in the source to indicate they should be skipped.

What is Eclipse trying to tell me?

[image: Eclipse Junit results]

Comment: just because you give methods a name with the word "test" in it, doesn't make them actual unit tests

Comment: Can you check if anything is getting printed on eclipse console that might be starting point of investigation.

Comment: The screenshot says `Runs 0/8`. There might somewhere a `System.exit(0);` or something similar in the test code that causes this. Instead of linking to `ConnectionTest.java`, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @howlger The code is from a publicly available open source Apache project available at the link in the question. To reproduce, check out the project and run "mvn test", as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was triggered by the unit test overriding Junit's run method as follows:

https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/ed3124e5fe223dada33ce6ddf53bc666063c3f2f/jackrabbit-jcr-server/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/webdav/server/WebDAVTestBase.java#L234

```
public void run(TestResult testResult) {
    if (Boolean.getBoolean("jackrabbit.test.integration")) {
        super.run(testResult);
    }
}
```

This was causing the test to not run at all.

In this case, Eclipse was picking up the test methods that should have been run and listed them, but with the tests not having been run, the Eclipse UI remains in a "vanilla" state.

This unit test obviously needs to be fixed to follow maven's best practise of splitting unit and integration tests into surefire and failsafe respectively, and not relying on a private mechanism.